# how to set Visual Studio 2012 to use JavaScript editor for asp files

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, visual-studio-2012

How can I tell Visual Studio 2012 to recognize Classic ASP files (extension .asp) as JavaScript? I have registered .asp extension to Script Editor. That used to do the trick in 2010, but doesn't help here. It seems like VS doesn't know what language to use for Script Editor. There is no keyword highlighting, no intelicense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be changed by adding the extension `asp` with the editor `HTML Editor`:

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `File Extension`

1. For `Extension` type: `asp`
2. Select the `HTML Editor`
3. Click `Add` (or `Apply` if you are updating an existing rule)

***EDIT:** Played around a bit and found out that you need to use `HTML Editor` and not `Web Form Editor`.*

***FINAL EDIT:*** As per comments below, should use the following Script tags around sections of JScript code to indicate to the editor to use JScript intellisense and highlighting:

```
<script language="JScript" runat="server">
// place your JScript code here
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried Web Form and Scrip Editor (and almost all others). The Web Form and Script Editor show text in black without color coding keywords, comments, etc. The closest one is C#, however since the syntax is wrong from the C# point of view, it wouldn't format as you type. Not even the indentation

Comment: See update, I think if you swap to HTML Editor you will get the intellisense for Classic ASP, such as Response, though I did find you need to need to 'force' it via Ctrl-Space (e.g. type "re" then press Ctrl-Space).

Comment: Html Editor does have some intellisense, however it seems like it thinks of server-side code as VB rather than JavaScript. Maybe there is a way to tell it to recognize it as JS?

Comment: from my understanding (could be wrong) in Classic ASP server-side code is VB. Are you meaning that you want JavaScript syntax colouring rather than JavaScript colouring?

Comment: Often server side code is VB, but not necessarily. In our case it's JavaScript. I noticed that if I put <%@language="JScript"%> at the top of a file then the editor knows to interpret it as JS. However I have a "main" file with language tag at the top followed by the include file directives. So the "main" is recognized correctly, but all the included are not and I cannot put the language tag in included files. Can I set the default language to be JS, then it would recognize the file correctly without the need for the tag.

Comment: Well, "JScript" is technically different to "JavaScript". Why can't you put the language tag on each of the included files? Also, this is somewhat different to the original question as now your talking about having multiple files included under a main file. Have you considered putting your script blocks into "<script language="JScript" runat="server"></script>" format? I would suggest that you create a new question over this and if my answer is correct for your specific question, mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: "<script language="JScript" runat="server"></script>" is client side tag, isn't it? And "<%@language="JScript"%>" is already present in the file with includes. Having more I believe will break things. The initial question is the same: How do I tell VS to treat .asp files as written in JavaScript language if nothing tells it otherwise

Comment: The runat="server" attribute on the script tag makes it server-side and not client-side. Have you tried to include the language tag on the other pages? If your unable to include the language tag on other pages than use the script tag with the runat="server" attribute. This should recognize the code inside the script tag as JScript.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. <script language="JScript" runat="server"> does seem to work. Whether I will be able use it or not is a completely different story, but it does solve the problem

Comment: glad to hear, I've updated my answer to include the server-side script tag to help others who might stumble upon this question in the future.

Comment: So if a classic asp file starts with <!-- include (JScript), you can't get valid syntax highlight? How very ugly, Microsoft!

I currently rename files to .asp, edit, then rename back to .inc.