# how to get javascript editor in phonegap app - Visual Studio 2012 express

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am starting with Visual Studio 2012 and porting a cordova/phonegap application, that's why I need to have a javascript editor for js file.

In order to get it, I followed this [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15938245/1948785)
but there is nothing for javascript and I cannot install any extension (because it is an express version).

Is there a way to get anything better and still using VS as IDE?

I created a cordova project this way:

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio supports javascript editing. You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: @Emre but what should I do to see a js file different that plain text?

Comment: Create a new javascript file in your solution explorer. Then copy your js code to that file you just created. You should be able to see it different than plain text.

Comment: I can only create new visual C# file not javascript doing rightclick->add->newItem

Comment: What kind of project did you create? You should create a web application

Comment: I added this info in my question

Comment: Are you going to deploy your application only to windows phone 8? I'd advice you to use the online build service of Phonegap,thus you can build for multiple platforms and you don't need to do these setup process.

Comment: phonebuild seems to work for basic apps only

Comment: You can add plugins for phonegapbuild too. If your app is too complicated, go with the native development.